# how can I link a CSS stylesheet in a Spotfire analysis?

Tags: javascript, css, spotfire

I can create a Javascript in Spotfire page however I have no idea how to add CSS files.

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 4):

this is not approved by Spotfire engineering, but you can inject a CSS that is hosted somewhere accessible to the machine running Spotfire (so, your local machine or a web player node) with JQuery:

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />');
```

so just put that into a JS inside a Text Area and voila!

one thing to note is that the file will be cached, you may want to update the code like:

```
var t = Date.now();
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css?t=' + t + '" type="text/css" />');
```

this will append the current timestamp to the URL of the stylesheet ensuring you get a fresh copy every time. it's advised to do this only until you're done modifying the CSS.